# Sum Formula in crystal reports based on two fields. Its working fine with one fields

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I have been working with summary formula in crystal report.
I am trying to calculate tution fee based on class, it is working f9 as shown below.

sum({Monthlyfeemaster.Tuition Fee},{Monthlyfeemaster.Class})

But I want to calculate  tution fee based on class and section, its gives error as shown below.

sum({Monthlyfeemaster.Tuition Fee},{Monthlyfeemaster.Class},{Monthlyfeemaster.Section})

Answer (score 0):

I would combine the class and section in another formula then add it to the sum formula

1. create a formula "class_section": 
   {Monthlyfeemaster.Class} & {Monthlyfeemaster.Section}
2. create a formula sum_tuition_class_section: 
   sum({Monthlyfeemaster.Tuition Fee}, {@class_section})

I'm not sure if you can get away with this:

sum({Monthlyfeemaster.Tuition Fee}, {Monthlyfeemaster.Class} & {Monthlyfeemaster.Section})

but above the steps above should work.

Comment: it is giving an error:" there must be group that matches this field"

Comment: Sorry, should have tested it before writing.  You probably already have a group for {Monthlyfeemaster.Class} since you are using sum({Monthlyfeemaster.Tuition Fee},{Monthlyfeemaster.Class}).  Thats the only way that code will work.  Create another group using the {@class_section} created in step 1.  Then step 2's formula will work...  Although, since you have the groups created, using the Insert > Summary... would be an easier solution.  Unless you are doing freaky calculations.

Answer (score 0):

```
sum({Monthlyfeemaster.Tuition Fee}, {Monthlyfeemaster.Class} & {Monthlyfeemaster.Section})
```

Change this to:

```
Tonumber({Monthlyfeemaster.Tuition Fee}) + Tonumber({Monthlyfeemaster.Class}) + Tonumber({Monthlyfeemaster.Section})
```